# ¿como bloquear el salto de linea en textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quiero que cuando se presione el enter **no salte de linea** en el textarea, eso lo quiero manejar yo. ¿Algún consejo o idea?

[image: quitar saltos de linea]

Comment: Hola @RuslanLopez, he visto que has modificado la pregunta, solo comentarte que tengas cuidado al editar las preguntas, ya que tal y como la has editado, has eliminado la segunda parte de la pregunta, es decir, la que al llegar un límite concreto, se realice el enter. Convendría que la volvieras a editar sin modificar el contexto global de lo que se pide en la pregunta original.

Comment: hola,yo no la edite la pregunta,de hecho no me gusta como quedó,cuando vi que me la cambiaron supuse que algún administrador la edito para que quedara más corta y directa con el fin de mejorar los post de la pagina

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Puedes usar una llamada al método [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) de Event para hacer que los eventos no se lancen. También te recomiendo ligar tu método a [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown), para que se ejecute antes de que se procese el comportamiento por defecto en tu html.

Es común ver este código con un `&& !e.shiftKey`, ya que nos permite pasar enter cuando se presiona el shift+enter, si deseas que siempre se impida, simplemente no lo incluyas y déjlo como `if(e.which === 13)`

```js
function pulsar(e) {
  if (e.which === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('prevented');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<textArea onkeydown="pulsar(event)">
</textArea>
```

Comment: funcionó perfectooo!,ya puedo dormir tranquilo gracias jaja

Answer (score 4):

Para detectar cuando el usuario presiona el botón Enter, puedes controlarlo mediante el evento `onkeypress`, llamando a una función en la que se active la función `preventDefault()` la cual anula el comportamiento normal del evento en caso de que se pulse dicho botón.

Además, para controlar el número de caracteres por línea podrás hacer uso las propiedades CSS `resize: none` que, junto con las propiedades `height` y `width` te limitarán el tamaño de tu textarea. Por otro lado, utilizando la propiedad `word-wrap: break-word` forzarás el salto de línea al final de la anchura de tu textarea.

```js
function cancelar() {
    var key = event.keyCode;

    if (key === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

```css
#textarea{
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" onkeypress="cancelar()"></textarea>
```